# BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt Error: Converting ONNX to Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, onnx, tf2onnx

When i run this code to convert onnx to tensorflow im getting error in google colab. I need to convert this onnx file to tensorflow lite so i can use it in android app.

```
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
import onnx

onnx_model_path = 'onnx_example.onnx'
tf_model_path = 'model_tf'

onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph(tf_model_path)
```

Getting below error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt         Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 9>()
> 7 onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)
> 8 tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
> ----> 9 tf_rep.export_graph(tf_model_path)
>
> 31 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_rep.py in
> export_graph(self, path)
> 141         self.tf_module,
> 142         path,
> --> 143         signatures=self.tf_module.**call**.get_concrete_function(
> 144             **self.signatures))
> 145     self.tf_module.is_export = False
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py
> in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)    1256   def
> get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs):    1257     # Implements
> GenericFunction.get_concrete_function.
> -> 1258     concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)    1259
> concrete._garbage_collector.release()  # pylint:
> disable=protected-access    1260     return concrete
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py
> in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 1236       if self._variable_creation_fn is None:    1237
> initializers = []
> -> 1238         self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)    1239
> self._initialize_uninitialized_variables(initializers)    1240
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py
> in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
> 761     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
> 762     self._concrete_variable_creation_fn = (
> --> 763         self._variable_creation_fn    # pylint: disable=protected-access
> 764         ._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
> 765             *args, **kwds))
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py
> in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
> **kwargs)
> 169     """Returns a concrete function which cleans up its graph function."""
> 170     with self._lock:
> --> 171       concrete_function, _ = self._maybe_define_concrete_function(args, kwargs)
> 172     return concrete_function
> 173
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py
> in _maybe_define_concrete_function(self, args, kwargs)
> 164       kwargs = {}
> 165
> --> 166     return self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
> 167
> 168   def _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py
> in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
> 394           kwargs = placeholder_bound_args.kwargs
> 395
> --> 396           concrete_function = self._create_concrete_function(
> 397               args, kwargs, func_graph)
> 398
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py
> in _create_concrete_function(self, args, kwargs, func_graph)
> 298
> 299     concrete_function = monomorphic_function.ConcreteFunction(
> --> 300         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
> 301             self._name,
> 302             self._python_function,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
> func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
> arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
> create_placeholders, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)    1212
> _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)    1213
> -> 1214       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)    1215     1216       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors,
> CompositeTensors,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py
> in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 665         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
> 666         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
> --> 667           out = weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> 668         return out
> 669
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py
> in bound_method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 482     # However, the replacer is still responsible for attaching self properly.
> 483     # TODO(mdan): Is it possible to do it here instead?
> --> 484     return wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
> 485
> 486   weak_bound_method_wrapper = weakref.ref(bound_method_wrapper)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)    1198           except
> Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except    1199             if
> hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> -> 1200               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)    1201             else:    1202               raise
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)    1187           # TODO(mdan):
> Push this block higher in tf.function's call stack.    1188
> try:
> -> 1189             return autograph.converted_call(    1190                 original_func,    1191                 args,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py
> in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
> 437     try:
> 438       if kwargs is not None:
> --> 439         result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
> 440       else:
> 441         result = converted_f(*effective_args)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py in
> tf____call__(self, **kwargs)
> 28                 output_ops = ag__.Undefined('output_ops')
> 29                 onnx_node = ag__.Undefined('onnx_node')
> ---> 30                 ag__.for_stmt(ag__.ld(self).graph_def.node, None, loop_body, get_state, set_state, (), {'iterate_names': 'node'})
> 31                 outputs = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(dict), (), None, fscope)
> 32
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, get_state, set_state,
> symbol_names, opts)
> 449     for_fn = *tf_distributed_iterable_for_stmt
> 450
> --> 451   for_fn(iter*, extra_test, body, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, opts)
> 452
> 453
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in *py_for_stmt(***failed resolving arguments***)
> 500   else:
> 501     for target in iter*:
> --> 502       body(target)
> 503
> 504
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in protected_body(protected_iter)
> 466     original_body = body
> 467     def protected_body(protected_iter):
> --> 468       original_body(protected_iter)
> 469       after_iteration()
> 470       before_iteration()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py in
> loop_body(itr)
> 21                     node = itr
> 22                     onnx_node = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(OnnxNode), (ag__.ld(node),), None, fscope)
> ---> 23                     output_ops = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).backend.*onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op,
> (ag*_.ld(onnx_node), ag__.ld(tensor_dict), ag__.ld(self).handlers),
> dict(opset=ag__.ld(self).opset, strict=ag__.ld(self).strict), fscope)
> 24                     curr_node_output_map = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(dict), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(zip),
> (ag__.ld(onnx_node).outputs, ag__.ld(output_ops)), None, fscope),),
> None, fscope)
> 25                     ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tensor_dict).update,
> (ag__.ld(curr_node_output_map),), None, fscope)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py
> in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
> 437     try:
> 438       if kwargs is not None:
> --> 439         result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
> 440       else:
> 441         result = converted_f(*effective_args)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py in
> tf___onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(cls, node, tensor_dict, handlers,
> opset, strict)
> 60                     pass
> 61                 handler = ag__.Undefined('handler')
> ---> 62                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(handlers), if_body_1, else_body_1, get_state_1, set_state_1, ('do_return', 'retval_'), 2)
> 63
> 64                 def get_state_2():
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names,
> nouts)    1264     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state,
> set_state, symbol_names, nouts)    1265   else:
> -> 1266     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1267     1268
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1317 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body,
> orelse):    1318   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if
> statement."""
> -> 1319   return body() if cond else orelse()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py in
> if_body_1()
> 54                         nonlocal retval_, do_return
> 55                         pass
> ---> 56                     ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(handler), if_body, else_body, get_state, set_state, ('do_return', 'retval_'), 2)
> 57
> 58                 def else_body_1():
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names,
> nouts)    1264     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state,
> set_state, symbol_names, nouts)    1265   else:
> -> 1266     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1267     1268
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1317 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body,
> orelse):    1318   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if
> statement."""
> -> 1319   return body() if cond else orelse()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py in if_body()
> 46                         try:
> 47                             do_return = True
> ---> 48                             retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(handler).handle, (ag__.ld(node),),
> dict(tensor_dict=ag__.ld(tensor_dict), strict=ag__.ld(strict)),
> fscope)
> 49                         except:
> 50                             do_return = False
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py
> in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
> 437     try:
> 438       if kwargs is not None:
> --> 439         result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
> 440       else:
> 441         result = converted_f(*effective_args)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py in
> tf__handle(cls, node, **kwargs)
> 39                     nonlocal retval_, do_return
> 40                     raise ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt),
> (ag__.converted_call('{} version {} is not implemented.'.format,
> (ag__.ld(node).op_type, ag__.ld(cls).SINCE_VERSION), None, fscope),),
> None, fscope)
> ---> 41                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(ver_handle), if_body, else_body, get_state, set_state, ('do_return', 'retval_'), 2)
> 42                 return fscope.ret(retval_, do_return)
> 43         return tf__handle
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names,
> nouts)    1264     _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state,
> set_state, symbol_names, nouts)    1265   else:
> -> 1266     _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1267     1268
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py
> in _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)    1317 def _py_if_stmt(cond, body,
> orelse):    1318   """Overload of if_stmt that executes a Python if
> statement."""
> -> 1319   return body() if cond else orelse()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py in
> else_body()
> 38                 def else_body():
> 39                     nonlocal retval_, do_return
> ---> 40                     raise ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt),
> (ag__.converted_call('{} version {} is not implemented.'.format,
> (ag__.ld(node).op_type, ag__.ld(cls).SINCE_VERSION), None, fscope),),
> None, fscope)
> 41                 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(ver_handle), if_body, else_body, get_state, set_state, ('do_return', 'retval_'), 2)
> 42                 return fscope.ret(retval_, do_return)
>
> BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt: in user code:
>
> ```
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py",
> ```
>
> line 99, in **call**  *
> output_ops = self.backend._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 347, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
> return handler.handle(node, tensor_dict=tensor_dict, strict=strict)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py",
> line 61, in handle  *
> raise BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt("{} version {} is not implemented.".format(node.op_type, cls.SINCE_VERSION))
>
> ```
> BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt: Unsqueeze version 13 is not implemented.
> ```

I tried to see the opset version like below

```
from onnx.defs import onnx_opset_version
onnx_opset_version()
```

It output

> 18

**Other things for your reference:**

```
import onnx

# Load the ONNX model
model = onnx.load("onnx_example.onnx")

# Check that the IR is well formed
onnx.checker.check_model(model)

# Print a Human readable representation of the graph
onnx.helper.printable_graph(model.graph)
```

> graph torch_jit (\n  %image_embeddings[FLOAT, 1x256x64x64]\n
> %point_coords[FLOAT, 1xnum_pointsx2]\n  %point_labels[FLOAT,
> 1xnum_points]\n  %mask_input[FLOAT, 1x1x256x256]\n
> %has_mask_input[FLOAT, 1]\n  %orig_im_size[FLOAT, 2]\n) initializers
> (\n  %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.self_attn.q_proj.bias[FLOAT,
> 256]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.bias[FLOAT, 256]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.bias[FLOAT, 256]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj.bias[FLOAT,
> 256]\n  %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.norm1.weight[FLOAT, 256]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.norm1.bias[FLOAT, 256]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.cross_attn_token_to_image.q_proj.bias[FLOAT,
> 128]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.cross_attn_token_to_image.k_proj.bias[FLOAT,
> 128]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.cross_attn_token_to_image.v_proj.bias[FLOAT,
> 128]\n
> %mask_decoder.transformer.layers.0.cross_attn_token_to_image.out_proj.bia...

How to solve this?
I found this github issue which they solved, but im not to able to find the solution https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/pull/1022

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm facing the same issue. My onnx generated is always 19 even with this line of code `torch.onnx.export(pytorch_model, dummy_input, onnx_model_path, opset_version=13)` and then I get `BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt: Unsqueeze version 13 is not implemented.` error when I try to export graph using `tf_rep.export_graph("tf_model")`